# R : How sum values in different colums without repetitions?

Tags: r, date

Here an example of my dataset

```
head(visite_cliente_date)
  CodCliente                                  museo       data Month January February March April May June July
1      76330                BORGO E ROCCA MEDIEVALE 2012-12-01    12       0        0     0     0   0    0    0
2      86660                BORGO E ROCCA MEDIEVALE 2012-12-01    12       0        0     0     0   0    0    0
3      87629                BORGO E ROCCA MEDIEVALE 2012-12-01    12       0        0     0     0   0    0    0
4     255734                BORGO E ROCCA MEDIEVALE 2012-12-01    12       0        0     0     0   0    0    0
5       1496 GAM - GALLERIA CIVICA ARTE MODERNA E C 2012-12-01    12       0        0     0     0   0    0    0
6      16689 GAM - GALLERIA CIVICA ARTE MODERNA E C 2012-12-01    12       0        0     0     0   0    0    0
  August September October November Dicember
1      0         0       0        0        1
2      0         0       0        0        1
3      0         0       0        0        1
4      0         0       0        0        1
5      0         0       0        0        1
6      0         0       0        0        1
```

CodCliente : ID customer

Mueso : Museum visited

data : Date of the visit

Month : Month of the visit

Every month : I created a dummy for each month according to "month" value

I'd like to create a new variable with the sum of the month in which the customer went to the museum.

Example : If the Customer went to the museum at least one time in march, April, and June, the variable has value "3".

Example2 : If the customer went three times in June to the museum, the variable has value "1".

Thanks in advance for the replies!

Comment: What did you try? Errors/undesired results? We hate to stifle your learning by doing your homework assignment!

Comment: My intention is to delete the variable “Museuo” and “month”, then reshape My data in a “wide” format, in order to do the Sum of the month for each Row, but I’m stuck because I can’t find a function to reshape My data as I want. I looked at melt and cast functions but they don’t seem to di the job

Comment: `rowSums(visite_cliente_date[5:16] > 0)`.

Comment: In my dataset there are repetition under “codCliente” basically each visit has a Row, so if someone did 3 visits he will appear in 3 Rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Finally Did it, but in a very long way

First of all, for each month, I created a dataset to sum visits.
Here I post what I did only for January

```
Gennaio <- subset(visite_cliente_date, January == 1)
Gennaio$Month <- NULL
Gennaio$February <- NULL
Gennaio$March <- NULL
Gennaio$April <- NULL
Gennaio$May <- NULL
Gennaio$June <- NULL
Gennaio$July <- NULL
Gennaio$August <- NULL
Gennaio$September <- NULL
Gennaio$October <- NULL
Gennaio$November <- NULL
Gennaio$Dicember <- NULL

Gennaio <- aggregate(Gennaio$January, list("ID" = Gennaio$CodCliente), sum)

Gennaio$January <- Gennaio$x
Gennaio$x <- NULL

head(Gennaio)
   ID January
1  41       1
2  94       1
3 106       5
4 111       1
5 113       1
6 118       1
```

Then I merged all my datasets replacing the NA values With 0

```
> Visite_mesi <- merge(Gennaio, Febbraio, by="ID", all=TRUE)
> Visite_mesi <- merge(Visite_mesi, Marzo, by="ID", all=TRUE)
> Visite_mesi <- merge(Visite_mesi, Aprile, by="ID", all=TRUE)
> Visite_mesi <- merge(Visite_mesi, Maggio, by="ID", all=TRUE)
> Visite_mesi <- merge(Visite_mesi, Giugno, by="ID", all=TRUE)
> Visite_mesi <- merge(Visite_mesi, Luglio, by="ID", all=TRUE)
> Visite_mesi <- merge(Visite_mesi, Agosto, by="ID", all=TRUE)
> Visite_mesi <- merge(Visite_mesi, Settembre, by="ID", all=TRUE)
> Visite_mesi <- merge(Visite_mesi, Ottobre, by="ID", all=TRUE)
> Visite_mesi <- merge(Visite_mesi, Novembre, by="ID", all=TRUE)
> Visite_mesi <- merge(Visite_mesi, Dicembre, by="ID", all=TRUE)

> Visite_mesi[is.na(Visite_mesi)] <- 0
    > 
   > head(Visite_mesi)
   ID January February March April May June July August September
1  41       1        0     0     0   0    0    0      0         0
2  94       1        2     1     1   1    1    0      0         0
3 106       5        9     6     3   4    6    1      7         7
4 111       1        3     1     1   3    5    0      0         0
5 113       1        1     0     0   0    0    0      0         3
6 118       1        0     1     1   0    1    0      1         0
  October November Dicember
1       0        0        0
2       1        0        0
3       3        4        5
4       0        0        0
5       0        0        0
6       0        0        0
```

At the end I Transformed values greater than 2 in 1

```
Visite_mesi$January[Visite_mesi$January >= 2] <- 1
Visite_mesi$February[Visite_mesi$February >= 2] <- 1
Visite_mesi$March[Visite_mesi$March >= 2] <- 1
Visite_mesi$April[Visite_mesi$April >= 2] <- 1
Visite_mesi$May[Visite_mesi$May >= 2] <- 1
Visite_mesi$June[Visite_mesi$June >= 2] <- 1
Visite_mesi$July[Visite_mesi$July >= 2] <- 1
Visite_mesi$August[Visite_mesi$August >= 2] <- 1
Visite_mesi$September[Visite_mesi$September >= 2] <- 1
Visite_mesi$October[Visite_mesi$October >= 2] <- 1
Visite_mesi$November[Visite_mesi$November >= 2] <- 1
Visite_mesi$Dicember[Visite_mesi$Dicember >= 2] <- 1
```

At the end I just summed all the values in month Columns, and so i Created the variable I wanted

```
> Visite_mesi$sum_month <- rowSums( Visite_mesi[,2:13] )
> head(Visite_mesi)
   ID January February March April May June July August September
1  41       1        0     0     0   0    0    0      0         0
2  94       1        1     1     1   1    1    0      0         0
3 106       1        1     1     1   1    1    1      1         1
4 111       1        1     1     1   1    1    0      0         0
5 113       1        1     0     0   0    0    0      0         1
6 118       1        0     1     1   0    1    0      1         0
  October November Dicember sum_month
1       0        0        0         1
2       1        0        0         7
3       1        1        1        12
4       0        0        0         6
5       0        0        0         3
6       0        0        0         5
```